# Our email bounces (550 5.7.26 Unauthenticated email from [mydomain])

Tags: g-suite, gmail

Our company uses Gsuite for gmail. But during the past months we have gotten more of our sent mails put in the recipient´s trashbin. I guess my domain has gotten into a spam list, but I dont know how to fix it

Now we only get bounced emails and this error message

> 550 5.7.26 Unauthenticated email from [mydomain] is not accepted
> due to domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of
> [mydomain] domain if this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the
> DMARC initiative. a66sor180704oif.146 - gsmtp

...Well, I AM the administrator and I have no clue on where to start. I have looked at googles support, but its just leads to one more generic article after another. The domain itself is at a webhost, I have seen something about adding a DMARC DNS-record, but I dont know what to insert into it, or even if its me (the sender) should do

HUGE thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have a DMARC policy on the domain name you use to send email.
(check corresponding Dmarc dns record of your domain to confirm. https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx can also be used for that)
But recipients complain  the email messages you send don’t comply with that policy.

Either change the DMARC record to reflect your actual mail practices OR ensure that the messages you send (via all outlets that you’re using including mail clients , mobile devices,  web forms and mailing lists) DO comply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used the tool and it says [DMARC Record Published:DMARC Record found], [DMARC Policy Not Enabled:DMARC Quarantine/Reject policy enabled].  Is this something my webhost may have set, or google? What does it mean to comply with DMARC?

Comment: The Dmarc policy is set as a dns record so it must have been set by somebody who has administrator access to those.  (Your web hosting provider if they also registered your domain is a possibility) A dmarc record is a policy (for instance “reject email messages that fail message checks”)  and recipients have the option to check your dmarc record and follow that policy when they receive a message from a sender using an email address in your domain.

Comment: ok, thanks for all clarifications! I will have a look as soon as I get home